# Java, extract just the fractional part of a BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In Java, I'm working with the `BigDecimal` class and part of my code requires me to extract the fractional part from it.  `BigDecimal` does not appear to have any built in methods to help me get the number after the decimal point of a `BigDecimal`.

For example:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("23452.4523434");
```

I want to extract the `4523434` from the number represented above.  What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I would try `bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE)`.

Uses the [`remainder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder-java.math.BigDecimal-) method and the [`ONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ONE) constant.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( "23452.4523434" );
BigDecimal fractionalPart = bd.remainder( BigDecimal.ONE ); // Result:  0.4523434
```

Comment: @Franklin -- please un-accept my answer and instead accept Taymon's answer since it is cleaner and overall better than mine. 1+ to Taymon.

Comment: Current solution's code would return "0.4523434", not "4523434" as the author wanted. Some more moves will be required.

Comment: its important to get only the "4523434" in some cases , this answer dont return the correct result ,  should print the output as well.

Comment: For performance sensitive applications, I measured this to be quite slow. The equivalent `BigDecimal fractionalPart = bd.subtract(new BigDecimal(bd.toBigInteger()))` is about 50x - 80x faster depending on scale.

Answer (score 17):

If the value is negative, using `bd.subtract()` will return a wrong decimal.

**Use this**:

```
BigInteger decimal = bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).movePointRight(bd.scale()).abs().toBigInteger();
```

It returns `4523434` for `23452.4523434` or `-23452.4523434`

---

In addition, if you don't want extra zeros on the right of the fractional part, use:

```
bd = bd.stripTrailingZeros();
```

before the previous code.

Comment: While your code is correct formally, it is not in reality. Imagine the input is `BigDecimal("123.45").setScale(6)` then you will get `450000`. Hardly a useful result.

Comment: @PavelVlasov that number will still be fractional part, which is the original question. Every zero on the right of "fractional part" is useless, so `45` or `450000` are equal in this context.

Comment: @PavelVlasov to solve your case, apply `bd = bd.stripTrailingZeros();` before my code.

Comment: Thanks for the strip function. Btw, such code is useful when one need to spell numbers (cents).

Comment: Careful here! if you have "5.009" you will get "9"

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative to using the `remainder()` method:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("23452.4523434");
BigDecimal fracBd = bd.subtract(new BigDecimal(bd.toBigInteger()));
```

Further, you can try the abs() method to ensure the fraction part is positive:

```
BigDecimal fracBd = bd.subtract(new BigDecimal(bd.toBigInteger())).abs();
```

Comment: Subtract without math-context can lead to some interesting results.

Comment: Doesnt extract  only "4523434" , this is not the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work!!!

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(23452.4523434);
BigInteger decimal = 
d.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).movePointRight(d.scale()).abs().toBigInteger();
```

When you input number, which fractional-part starts with '0', for ex. "123.00456".
You get "456" instead of "00456".
It happens because we convert it `.toBigInteger()`, and **the first zeros just gone**;
If you use `.toString()` instead of `.toBigInteger()`, you get 456.00000, **it's wrong too!**

So my advise is **using this**:

```
BigDecimal fractPart = bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fractPart.toString());
sb.delete(0, 2);
String str = sb.toString();
```

And then just use this `str` how you want