# sqlite convert timestamp to date

Tags: java, sqlite, date, timestamp

how to convert timestamp value 444663422.631236 to date. I tried these ways but does not worked.

```
public class Teste {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String l = "480364794";
    String d = "479617200";

    print(convertEpoc("444663422"));

    print(convert("480364794", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    print(convert("479617200", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

}

private static String convertEpoc(String d) {
    long epoch = Long.parseLong(d);
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch * 1000);
    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    return instant.toString();
}

public static String convert(String epochSec, String dateFormatStr) {
    Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochSec) * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatStr,
            Locale.getDefault());
    return format.format(date);
}

public static void print(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `convert` seems to be OK, and what jar did you use in `convertEpoc`?

Comment: @JoséHolandaNeto What do you mean by “does not worked”? What did you expect and what did you get instead?

Comment: @ JoséHolandaNeto Why do you give one kind of example input in the first sentence, but then give entirely different inputs in your example code? Please work to organize your thoughts before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question in inconsistent with two different kinds of input. First we will look at the whole seconds, then we will look at the input with a decimal fraction.

## Whole Seconds

No need for multiplying by a thousand when the input is a count of seconds since [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class offers the static method [`ofEpochSecond`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-) to handle whole seconds.

## `OffsetDateTime`

When working with only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (or [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself), use the [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class. The `ZonedDateTime` class is for assigning a full time zone. A full time zone is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

So what is the difference between an `Instant` and an `OffsetDateTime` assigned UTC as the offset? No difference in the meaning, both represent the same moment. But the `OffsetDateTime` has additional features. One such feature is flexible formatting when generating a String representation, whereas an `Instant` is not intended for formatting other than its own `toString` method.

```
String input = "480364794";
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( Long.parseLong ( input ) );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC );

System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | instant: " + instant + " | odt: " + odt );
```

When run.

> input: 480364794 | instant: 1985-03-22T18:39:54Z | odt: 1985-03-22T18:39:54Z

## Fractional Second

For the input of a fractional second, separate the whole number of seconds from the fraction. Then pass each to a static factory method, [`Instant.ofEpochSecond`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-) taking two arguments.

One way of getting those numbers is through `BigDecimal`. We do not use `double`/`float` because those data types trade away accuracy for speed of execution.

See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10038749/642706) for discussion of extracting fractional part of a `BigDecimal`. Note especially [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10038770/642706) and [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779709/642706).

```
BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal ( "444663422.631236" );

// Seconds
long seconds = input.longValue ();  // = 444,663,422. Truncates the fraction. Only the whole number portion remains.

// Nanoseconds
BigDecimal fractionalSecond = input.remainder ( BigDecimal.ONE );  // = 0.631236. Truncates whole number. Only decimal fraction remains.
int decimalPlacesForNanoseconds = 9;
if ( fractionalSecond.scale () > decimalPlacesForNanoseconds ) {  // Too many decimal places?
    // FIXME: Handle this error condition. This means data loss as our input has a granularity finer than nanoseconds.
    System.out.println ( "ERROR - Input finer than nanoseconds. Message # 0aa71e3b-6a5b-4ac4-b239-68e6b9f12284." );
}
BigInteger nanosBI = fractionalSecond.movePointRight ( decimalPlacesForNanoseconds ).toBigInteger ();  // Make a whole number from the fraction.
long nanos = nanosBI.longValue ();

// Instant = ( Seconds + Nanoseconds )
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( seconds , nanos );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | seconds: " + seconds + " | nanos: " + nanos + " | instant: " + instant );
```

When run.

> input: 444663422.631236 | seconds: 444663422 | nanos: 631236000 | instant: 1984-02-03T13:37:02.631236Z